# Show values on chart Using System.Web.Helpers.Chart

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, charts

I am using **System.Web.Helpers.Chart** for charting in MVC3, charts are rendering fine, but i want to add the value of at the top of the bar I tried a lot but failed to find a way to show value of respective bar,Is it possible using System.Web.Helpers.Chart?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Well, you are either going to use the MS built in charts with `System.Web.Helpers.Chart` or you are going to use HighCharts. One is a .NET library and the other is a js library. You may be able to use the built in .NET methods to parse the data to a format you need but you are going to have send that to highcharts. Will need more info on what you are doing.